# Error connecting to mySQL database from C# application

Tags: c#, mysql, database, connection-string

I'm trying to connect to a  mySQL database from C# application but getting the following error.

> Keyword not supported: 'database'.

The mySQL.Net connector version is 6.9.6

Following is the connection string in my app.config file.

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ABC.DAL.CONN.MySql" providerName="DataProvider.MySql" connectionString="SERVER =MyServer; database =my_database; UID =admin; Pwd =Dba49!;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Following is the piece of code that connects to MySQL database for bulkinsert -

```
             MySqlConnection mySqlConn = new MySqlConnection(dbConnString);
            MySqlBulkLoader obSBC = new MySqlBulkLoader(mySqlConn);
            obSBC.Columns.Add("CUSTOMER_ID");
            obSBC.Columns.Add("VEHICLE_NUMBER");
                 obSBC.TableName = "TX_CUSTOMER";
            obSBC.FieldTerminator = @",";
            obSBC.FileName = strFilePath + strFileName;
            obSBC.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 0;
            obSBC.Priority = MySqlBulkLoaderPriority.None;
            obSBC.Timeout = 2000;
            obSBC.ConflictOption = MySqlBulkLoaderConflictOption.None;
            int countRecords = obSBC.Load();
```

I checked a lot of forums but unable to resolve the error.

Comment: Not sure if the connection string is key sensitive, but would you please type database with capital "D" and "Uid". Inform us for the result.

Comment: @sandeep replace your connectionString and let us know if it works: connectionString="SERVER=MyServer;Database=my_database;UID=admin;Pwd=Dba49!;"

Answer (score 0):

There is an [old bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52365) in MySQL that under certain conditions makes connection strings case sensitive. AFAIK I know this has never been fixed.

Please try deleting all the whitespaces from your connection string and write the keyword Database (and it's value, if that is in Caps too) in Caps.